# WPF - DataGridTemplate with DataTemplate.Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers

I need to get different types of rows in one column, so I'm trying to use `DataGridTemplate` with triggers. I'm sending `Class = {Value = "Something", Type = "comboBox"}` but `comboBox1` is not showing.

```xaml
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="comboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Height="22" Name="comboBox1">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox template column is incorrect, this works fine:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" Width="400" Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding Address}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address}" Value="Pune">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address}" Value="Mumbai">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox Height="22" Name="comboBox1">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Address}" Value="Mumbai">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.Style>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is working, please change the trigger binding values to your Type. I have used Address values for example, you use your values.

Comment: This will show combobox every time, I want to show it ONLY if ``Type == "comboBox"``

Comment: I have edited the answer, please use this template and just change the trigger values to suit your needs.

Comment: I gave you +1 for interesting solution, but this adds two elements in one row, not one, so it's not really a solution to my problem.

Comment: But why does it matter if it adds two elements? Only one is going to be visible at a time depending on <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="comboBox">

Answer (score 1):

Moving `DataTemplate` to `Style` somehow fixed my problem, but it's still not working as intended.

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="comboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Height="22" Name="comboBox1">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>                                
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```